# How does an analog metal rod stop a water pump by touching water?

Tags: voltage, conductivity, underwater

I’m currently building a steamer (like on an espresso machine) and the part that tells the water pump to stop sending water in the boiler is a simple rod of metal inserted in the actual boiler.

Now, I’m trying to make my pump stop when water touches the rod of metal but I don’t know how I could make it work like the usual espresso machine does. How does the contact of water makes the pump stop? Is it a difference in voltage because the water acts as a ground? Is it a comparator checking the difference in voltage?

Anyways, with either of the outcomes, I’ve tested putting the rod in water with DC current (not AC) and the voltage doesn’t change at all on my voltmeter. So, one solution I came with would be to put two rods in the boiler. Both with positive charges. The first one send DC continuously in the rod and the other turns on once water gives it conduction through the water. This then opens a closed circuit (switch) that removes power from the pump.

So this is the solution I came with but usually, in espresso machines, you only have one rod that does the whole job. Could you enlighten me? Also, I’m not sure why but the pump that I ordered from an espresso machine shop seems to be working with AC. So I’d have to send AC in the pump but DC in the rod that should control the pump?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome!

Why does the one rod solution work?  Well, that is because the circuit for the current flowing out of the rod is completed by the **tank that holds the water**.  If the water tank (or boiler, in your case) is conductive, then this forms one connection to the water, while the other connection is due to the rod.  When the water level reaches the rod the water completes the circuit and there will be a distinctive change in impedance that can be detected by a relatively simple circuit.

In the case where the water tank is not conductive, then of course DC current flow is not possible, however, AC current flow is indeed possible - the exact amount of current flow will depend on many factors, mainly the geometry of the tank and its proximity to a conductive path to complete the circuit from the rod.  In this case, there will be a distinctive change (reduction) in the AC impedance when the water touches the rod.

Many water level detectors apply an alternating AC waveform to the rod, and detect the AC current flow out from that rod.  This detection can be done in many ways, one very simple way is to have a simple oscillator provide a square-wave voltage that is connected to the rod via a resistor (or capacitor).  The voltage at the rod is monitored by a simple AC to DC detector.  When the water is not touching the rod, the current flow will be very small (almost zero) and so the voltage at the detector output will be high.  When the water touches the rod the current flow will be much higher causing a voltage drop across the series resistor, and the detector output voltage will reduce significantly.

Comment: So my boiler might be made of stainless steel or copper (pretty different I know). But whatever material I choose doesn’t matter since water would conduct the electricity anyways right? 

Also, if I send AC to the rod, isn’t that a bit more risky than DC? I mean, the water in this boiler will be drank so I don’t know! If I do send AC, won’t the wall outlet jump? What should I use? 

Regarding the method to control the pump from the rod, how would the assembly work? Do I connect a small oscillator to a capacitor and link the capacitor to the rod? Where would be the AC to DC detector?

Comment: @bernardleclerc  I suggest making the amplitude of the AC voltage applied to the rod very low - so that it is safe and cannot cause any problems to anyone touching it.  Something like, say, 5V peak-to-peak.  This can be generated from a simple oscillator circuit (the sort used to teach basic electronics to high-school students) which is supplied power from a simple DC supply such a phone charger.

Comment: You mean a simple AC supply such as a phone charger? Also, in order to change my 120V to 5V, do I take a voltage regulator?

Comment: The phone charger provides a safe, low-voltage DC output (about 5V dc).  This can power a small circuit that provides (a) the low-voltage AC signal to the rod, and (b) the detector to tell you when the water has touched the rod.

Comment: Sorry to make you repeat yourself, but how does the charging block notices the change in voltage? Mostly, how does it stop the pump? Not an electrician so learning along the way!

Comment: The charger only provides DC power.  You then need a separate circuit that provides the signal to the rod, and then yet another circuit to detect when the water has touched the rod.  You then need a relay (or something similar) to tell the pump when to start and stop.  So you need to engage someone who can design this for you.  Many of the building blocks I have mentioned may already be available from your local electrical suppliers.  Please, whatever you do, do **not** put high voltage on the rod, and by high voltage I mean anything more than 30Vac.

Answer (score 0):

Circuit breakers are required to last 10000 operations. Thus in theory you could use a ground fault (=residual current) breaker to turn a device off when the water level rise causes a new current which knocks off the balance. The breaker must be reset manually. I guess it's an advantage.

To stay alive and without burning anything nor anyone be sure that the homemade circuits work ALL with safe low voltages which are isolated from the mains AC with a transformer. The breaker works as well with low voltages.

A qualified electrician may have the knowledge to work with the non-isolated mains AC, but even his appliance constructions probably are illegal to be used as tools which are used by others. Here's a principle which might be possible for a person who knows what he does:

[image]

The imbalance current through the water is made as isolated. Selecting proper transformer and resistors needs measurements and calculations. R1 weakens the idle primary current so much that it cannot trip the breaker without the water. R2 prevents the full short circuit of the secondary. As I said, measurements and calculations are a must. Get local help if you cannot do them. The same for safe construction!

Do NOT try to connect the imbalance current straight from the bottom of the R1 without a transformer, no matter how attractive it seems to be - at least as long as you have not touched the water sensing rod. Besides such attempt could trip the actual ground fault breaker in your main AC distribution system and cause an instant blackout.

Comment: Great thank you!

Comment: Wow yes that is a good representation thanks. Might need help on building this one indeed. By the way, do you think that this would be the most efficient way of controlling the pump with the rod?

Comment: The "most efficient way" depends on what one happens to already have in his material and component inventory, his skill level, available equipment and what he can afford without causing any harms in other sectors. This one needs only knowlwdge and parts that any proper electrician can understand - no programming, no analog nor computer circuit design knowledge nor advanced electronics lab tools like an oscilloscope. But it still needs solid understanding and knowledge at electrician level. My sketch is only a starting point, it's not a ready to use construction drawing.

Answer (score 0):

AC is generally preferred over DC to avoid corrosion of one of the metal elements (the boiler cannister or the electrode).  If you pass a DC current through water, between two electrodes, then one of the electrodes will gradually be eroded away, with new metal being deposited on the other electrode.

Running a low voltage AC current through the water constantly reverses the direction of the erosion and deposition.  So the electrodes last a lot longer.
AC is perfectly safe if the voltage is low enough.